# Avoid user from overriding default mapred property in hadoop 2

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, hive-configuration

How to avoid user from overriding the default property of hadoop configuration file when submitting hive  jobs?

Exmaple:

mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.job.heap.memory-mb.ratio</name>
    <value>0.8</value>
  </property>
```

User use below propery in hive job to override

```
set mapreduce.job.heap.memory-mb.ratio=0.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Hadoop documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html):

> Configuration parameters may be declared final. Once a resource
>   declares a value final, no subsequently-loaded resource can alter that
>   value *(...)* Administrators typically define parameters as final in core-site.xml for values that user applications may not alter.

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.hosts.include</name>
  <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/hosts.include</value>
  <final>true</final>
</property>
```

So, if your users connect via JDBC, you just have to tinker with the config. files used by HiveServer2 to make some props "final".

If your users connect with the legacy `hive` CLI, and they are not hackers, you just have to *(a)* tinker with the global conf for Hadoop clients, or *(b)* tinker with the "hive" launcher script so that it picks specific config files in a non-default directory (typically done by forcing the custom dir ahead of the standard Hadoop CLASSPATH).

If your users are hackers and they have access to the legacy `hive` CLI, they could override the config files themselves so technically you cannot enforce `<final>` properties. But anyway, if someone can achieve that, then he/she will probably get your job anyway ;-)